# regex catch inline math formula, ex: $ inline $ in python or javascript

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have a string input (a content of a markdown file), where every math formula enclosed by $$.

Ex:

```
$$ stand alone $$

$$ stand 
alone $$


And there $$ inline $$. 

$$ inline 2 $$ some text also.
```

I would like to change the *inline* formulas to be enclosed by $.

I tried to catch with regex, but so far I can not come up with the right solution.

This one example catch every $$ but do not distinct inline and stand-alone:

```py
re.findall(r'\$\$([^\$]+?)\$\$',  txt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use look-ahead and look-behind to check if theres text before or after the formula like so:

```py
re.findall(r'(?:(?<=(?: |\w))\$\$([^\n$]+?)\$\$)|(?:\$\$([^\n$]+?)\$\$(?=(?: |\w)))',  txt)
```

This yields:

```
[(' inline ', ''), ('', ' inline 2 ')]
```

you can learn more about look aheads/behinds [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and test your patterns [here](https://regex101.com/).

Edit: removed unnecessary escaping in `[\n\$]` as suggested in Bosoeng Choi's comment.

Comment: thanks the solution and the links, this is which I was looking for.

Comment: `\$` has unnecessary escaping in `[^\n\$]`. `[^\n$]` is more simple(recommended by Pycharm).

Answer (score 2):

First, you can use `.*+` instead of `[^$]+`. It doesn't capture patterns which include `\n`.

Then, put "not at starting of line-`(?!^)`"
and "not at ending of line-`(?<!$)`". And use `|` to combine them.

```py
print(re.findall(r'(?m)(?!^)\$\$(.+?)\$\$|\$\$(.+?)\$\$(?<!$)', txt))
```

will print:

```py
[(' inline ', ''), ('', ' inline 2 ')]
```

`(?m)` indicates "multiline" flag.

If you want to replace those to `REPLACED!!`,

```py
print(re.sub(r'(?m)(?!^)\$\$(.+?)\$\$|\$\$(.+?)\$\$(?<!$)', '$$ REPLACED!! $$', text))
```

output:

```
$$ stand alone $$

$$ stand 
alone $$


And there $$ REPLACED!! $$. 

$$ REPLACED!! $$ some text also.
```

---

If you dislike that group number is not consistent,

You can use conditional pattern:

```py
print(re.findall(r'(?m)(.+)?\$\$(.+?)\$\$(?(1)|.+)', text))
```

output:

```py
[('And there ', ' inline '), ('', ' inline 2 ')]
```

Now the target group number is always 2.

Comment: Thanks, it is very nicely explaind.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the start in your regex by adding `^`.

Like `^\$\$([^\$]+?)\$\$`

Comment: How will that change the inline formulas to be enclosed by $?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the stand alone formulas in a capturing group surrounded by anchors and use an alternation `|` with another group to capture the the content between the inline formulas.

In the replacement, place back group 1 and 2 where group 2 is surrounded by a single `$`

```
^(\$\$[\s\S]*?\$\$)$|(?<!\$)\$(\$[\s\S]*?\$)\$(?!\$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aplk3K/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/r0X4J2)

*Example code*

```
import re

pattern = r"^(\$\$[\s\S]*?\$\$)$|(?<!\$)\$(\$[\s\S]*?\$)\$(?!\$)"
test_str = ("$$ stand alone $$\n\n"
            "$$ stand \n"
            "alone $$\n\n"
            "And there $$ inline $$. ")

regex = re.compile(pattern, re.MULTILINE)
result = re.sub(
    regex,
    lambda x: x.group(2) if x.group(2) else x.group(1), test_str
)

if result:
    print (result)
```

*Output*

```
$$ stand alone $$

$$ stand 
alone $$

And there $ inline $.
```